# Keeping Multiple Embedded Signers and Remote Signers on the same document

Tags: docusignapi

We can generate multiple Remote Signers web request and keep all the signatures from Remote signers on the same document based on the workflow and Routing Order.

The main challenge we are facing is:
If we have multiple Embedded signers and Remote signers on the same document.
How can we send the setup the web service request so that all the Signatures are captured on the same document.

Seems like for each Embedded signer an unique signing URLs is generated.
Is there a way we can maintain the same envelop for all the signers?

Please advise.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sure, that's easy.  For any recipient who will sign through [Embedded Signing](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign) you need to set their `clientUserId` property when you add them to the envelope.  For remote signers simply do not include this property at all in those recipients' definitions.

To control the order of signing use the `routingOrder` property for each recipient. Note that you can only generate a signing URL for a recipient when it is their turn in the routing order, and that both serial and parallel routing is supported by the DocuSign platform.

For example, to have 3 people sign in order where the first and third recipients sign through embedded signing and the second is a remote signer - i.e. initiates through an email notification - you could use this JSON:

```
{
    "status": "sent",
    "emailSubject": "Embedded and Remote Signers",
    "documents": [{
        "documentId": "1",
        "name": "contract.pdf",
        "documentBase64": "base64 document bytes...",
    }],
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [
            {
                "email": "john@email.com",
                "name": "John Doe",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "clientUserId": "1001"
            },
            {
                "email": "sally@email.com",
                "name": "Sally Doe",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "routingOrder": "2"
            },
            {
                "email": "bob@email.com",
                "name": "Bob Doe",
                "recipientId": "3",
                "routingOrder": "3",
                "clientUserId": "1002"
            }                       
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. We are trying to simulate basically the docusign "sign now" using the embedded signing functionality using the web service and web UI for multiple embedded signers without generating the signing url. We can only place one anchor tab on the document using the embedded signer option. If we send the multiple embedded signers on the same call other tags do not display on the document.  Please advise how we can place multiple sign here anchor tabs for multiple embedded users. Again thanks much for your help.

Comment: Only one signer can sign at a time.  Each signer can have their own unique anchor string so that DocuSign knows where that signer needs to sign.  Each signer will see their tab when they view the envelope/document(s).

Comment: We are sending unique anchor string in PDF byte array for each signers. However here is the challenge we are facing;

Comment: We are sending unique anchor string in PDF byte array for each signers.We have two types of roles assigned to the same document: Remote and Embedded .  Challenge is: If multiple embedded signers are specified for example, Husband and wife for the document both of them will have to sign the document at the same time. Embedded signers should sign the document using the docusign UI called directly from the Calling application. Same document also has Remote signers. Not sure how we can keep all of them together on the same envelop using the same web service call. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Works if one embedded signer is assigned first and subsequent signers are remote. As soon as first embedded singers finishes signing document email request is sent to Remote signer. Again the challenge is keeping multiple embedded signers together via web service call who are signing at the same time or at least generate multiple embedded signing URLs and assign the signing order within the same Document envelop.

Comment: How do you tell the workflow to embedded signers? For example.  We would like to tell signer "A"  After Signer A completes the singing, the envelopes will be sent to Signer "B" and After Signer "B"   envelop Will be sent to Signer "C".